# How to pass argument from one form to another form in ax 2012

Tags: axapta

Table has one date field. I have two form name as formA and formB ,formA has textbox and button. formB has grid with date field.

So my question is if I enter date in textbox and clicked the button of formA, entered date should be assign in grid of formB. I added table datasource of both forms. Please help me out on this.

Comment: Share your code here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a parameter between two forms in Axapta?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258375/how-to-pass-a-parameter-between-two-forms-in-axapta)

Answer (score 1):

Although behavior described by you seems to be not so standard in terms of AX, I would suggest you to use dialog form as a FormA (rather than regular form). That way you respect best practices and desired behavior is achieved easier.

Create class extending RunBase class with date field:

```
class FormADialog extends RunBase
{
    DialogField fieldDate; 
    TransDate   transDate;
}
```

Here is how we construct form controls:

```
protected Object Dialog()
{
    Dialog dialog = super();
    fieldDate = dialog.addField(extendedTypeStr(TransDate), 'Date');
    return dialog;
}
```

The following method will retrieve values from Dialog:

```
public boolean getFromDialog()
{
    transDate = fieldDate.value();
    return super();
}
```

Processing logic goes here:

```
public void run()
{
    FormBTable formBTable;

    ttsbegin;

    select firstOnly forUpdate formBTable;
    formBTable.Date = transDate;
    formBTable.write();

    ttscommit;
}
```

The only missing thing is entry point for dialog class (represents FormA):

```
public static void main(Args _args)
{        
    FormADialog     formADialog = new FormADialog();
    FormDataSource  formDataSource;

    if (formADialog.prompt())
    {
        formADialog.run();

        // FormB should contain menu item for dialog class for the following code
        if (args && args.record() && args.record().dataSource())
        {
            formDataSource =  args.record().dataSource();
            formDataSource.research();
        }
    }
}
```

Now clicking on dialog button will update grid.

If you insist on use of approach with two regular forms. I will think of `linkActive()` method at the datasource of the second form. Take a look at 
[Tutorial Form Dynalink](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=Tutorial_Form_Dynalink). A record change in the parent form notifies the child form, making it call the linkActive method which in turn calls the executeQuery method at the child table datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be as follows.

For passing parameters from one form to another a special class **Args** is usually used.

Initiator form prepares data for transfer within clicked() method of button control:

```
void clicked() 
{
   Args            args;
   FormRun         formRun;

   args = new Args();
   args.parm(dateField.text());       
   args.name(formStr(FormB));

   formRun = classFactory.formRunClass(args);
   formRun.init();
   formRun.run();
   formRun.wait();

   super();
}
```

Receiving endpoint should listen at init() method of FormB:

```
public void init() 
{
   Date passedValue;

   super();              

   // check presence
   if (element.args())
   {
       passedValue = str2Date(element.args().parm(), 123);
   }
}
```

[Take a look at axaptapedia.com article to see how we can pass complex set of parameters within custom made class.](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Passing_values_between_forms)