# How to pass argument from form to dialog? AX

Tags: axapta, x++, args

I created clicked() method in menuItemButton

```
  Args            args;
   args = new args();
   args.parm(CustTable.AccountNum);
   super();
```

And in dialog run

```
 str             anyStringValueFromCaller;
    ;
    super();


    if( element.args() )
    {
        // get string parameter
        anyStringValueFromCaller = element.args().parm();

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a parameter between two forms in Axapta?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258375/how-to-pass-a-parameter-between-two-forms-in-axapta)

Comment: Yes I read that. But I have to make dialog box. And this clues doesn't work on dialog. :(

Comment: Why not? A dialog is a form.

Answer (score 2):

If the dialog is indeed a form in AOT, you should have no problems using args.record() or args.parm(), you should do as described at [How to pass a parameter between two forms in Axapta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258375/how-to-pass-a-parameter-between-two-forms-in-axapta)

If you are dynamically creating a dialog from x++, well, you are still able to override event methods on controls as described here: [Override the event methods on dialog controls in Dynamics AX](http://axforum.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/override-event-methods-on-dialog.html).

Just one suggestion though: don't you args.parm() unless you really need to, looking at the sample code you posted, it is perfectly ok to use args.record() instead.